# 2 divs in the parent div(flex), first div is fixed width - expand second width to the rest

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
}// This is also flex parent div
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to expand the second div to the rest? I don't want to use **calc** for second div style.

Comment: set flex-grow: 1 on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex` property value to `1` for `.second` class. This will fit the second div to rest of width.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `flex:1` to the `.second` div (borders included to show the actual size)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
</div>
```

This will set the [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property to `1`